# 'Unwanted tags' as an addition to the 'Favourite tags'

Tags: feature-request, tags, questions, filtering

Is it possible to set some kind of *Unwanted tags* as an addition to the *Favourite tags*?

For example, I **want to see** questions with some specific tags so I place those tags in my ***Favourites tags***:

[image]

But there is also a group of tags which I **don't want to see**.

Is it possible to define such group of tags which are *Unwanted*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your Ignored Tags are not shown by default in the right bar. When you click the *edit* button, your Favorite Tags become editable *and* a new Ignored Tags section appears below that.

You can also find your Ignored Tags by visiting your profile and clicking the preferences link. This page includes the option of what you want the site to *do* with the tags you ignore: either grey them out (make them opaque) or completely hide them from the list.